# What alternatives exist to Sitemesh to help layout JSP/JSTL page footers/headers in a Spring MVC app?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, sitemesh

I've tried excluding certain pages from my Sitemesh decorator but it doesn't seem to follow its own logic:

```
<decorators>
    <excludes>
        <pattern>/register</pattern>
    </excludes>
</decorators>
```

What alternatives exist to Sitemesh that could serve as a drop-in replacement in a Spring MVC app that uses mainly plain JSP/JSTL?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried tiles (http://tiles.apache.org/)? I have used it with spring mvc (but freemarker and not jsp)..

Comment: Message from the future: The TIles project has been retired.